# Stored Procedure returns nothing

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

This might be a simple fail on my part, but I just can't figure out where or how.
I've been coding a windows service that is doing a bunch of things. One of which is inserting and getting data from a MS Sql 2005 database through stored procedures.

The following code is part of a windows service and now also a windows form, where both produce the same empty result.

```
    try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("U_RfId_ProductNumberGet", connectionRFID);
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            //SqlParameter paramProd = new SqlParameter();
            SqlParameter paramOut = new SqlParameter();
            paramOut.ParameterName = "@ProductInformation";
            paramOut.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            paramOut.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar;
            paramOut.Size = 50;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(paramOut);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductNumber", content); //content = "1" for testing
            connectionRFID.Open();

            textBox1.Text = (String)paramOut.Value;

            //cmd.Parameters["@ProductInformation"].Value.ToString();
            connectionRFID.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { textBox1.Text = ex.Message;
        connectionRFID.Close();
        }
```

And then there's the SP the code is calling. I've tried changing it to only return a resultset instead of a scalar output parameter and then the call to the SP works, but I'd prefer to use the scalar values.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE U_RfId_ProductNumberGet
@ProductInformation     varchar(50) OUTPUT,
@ProductNumber          varchar(8)

AS
BEGIN TRAN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
BEGIN
SELECT @ProductInformation
                = CAST(vareNummer AS varchar(10)) 
                + '-' + CAST(vareTekst AS varchar(30))
FROM VareNummerVareTekst
WHERE ProductNumber = @ProductNumber
END
COMMIT TRAN
```

As a side note: If I execute the SP through SQL Management Studio I get a valid result.

Anyone notice what I've forgotten?

Comment: You did not Execute the Command

Comment: Why are you using a transaction on a select operation?

Comment: @Baboon Its not me who made the SP that the service will be running with. Its a database manager from a company that supplied me a SP name and what to give as input and get as output. I've made my own(which is the one on display) for testing purposes that acts in the same way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to execute the command.

```
cmd.Execute(); // to get a resultset
```

or

```
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // to get output parameters but no resultset
```

should do it depending on whether or not you want a resultset.

Comment: That depends on whether or not he's still trying to get a resultset back

Comment: Yea, that does it... I've been bungling around with different types of executing it and accidentally removed it.
After I've apparently removed it I've changed the size of the parameters to 50 instead of 40, as I noticed the output parameter was 42. Could that have any impact aswell?

Comment: In my experience having different sizes of strings simply cuts off some data but should not result in non-execution

Comment: Yea, just changed it back to 40 and it just shows less of the string. I've no idea then what made it change - since I've tried ExecuteNonQuery before. I guess I made some sort of minor change that I havent noticed in between. :/

Answer (score 2):

you have to use ExecuteNonQuery on command object. [SqlCommand Executenonquery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

```
    connectionRFID.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // this missing from your code 
   textBox1.Text = (String)paramOut.Value;
```